How to animate the show/hide of the keyboard with jetpack compose?
Example of what i need can be found in very first video in https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/sw-keyboard

A combination of imePadding and imeNestedScroll would do.
Column(Modifier.imeNestedScroll()) {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        items(30) {
            Text(text = "Item #$it", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
        }
    }
    TextField(
        value = "",
        onValueChange = { },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().imePadding()
    )
}


edgeToEdge and android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" might also be needed in the activity's onCreate and AndroidManifest.xml.
Detailed explanation in the official docs

It's not the same what i want. In video above keyboard opens smoothy after click on TextField, not after scrolling.
